# [NSTaggedPointerString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner in iOS programming using Objective-c. I am now working on my project and found this weird error in the view controller.

```
2015-11-16 20:17:10.631 WeMakeFriends[1860:67214] -[NSTaggedPointerString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00296c6c756e286
2015-11-16 20:17:10.635 WeMakeFriends[1860:67214] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:'[NSTaggedPointerString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00296c6c756e286'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e3af45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001068b4deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e4356d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d90eea ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d90a98 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   WeMakeFriends                       0x0000000105f49f4c -[EditProfileViewController saveInfo:] + 108
```

It seems like when I try to get the text from the UITextField or UITextView, something is wrong. In order to dismiss the keyboard after editing textfields and textviews, I set them as the delegate for the view controller. 
Below is some part of the code:

```
@interface EditProfileViewController () <UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userAge;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *school;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *something;
@property DatabaseManager *dbManager;
@property NSArray *queryResult;
@property (copy, )NSString *textviewCopy;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //[self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
// set UITextView placeholder text
    [self.something setText:@"I want to ..."];
    self.something.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
// initialize the database manager
    _dbManager = [[DatabaseManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"users.sql"];

// load the user data if you inserted it before and come back to this view controller again
    if (self.currentUser.name.length != 0) {
        [self loadUser];
    } else {
    // load the user data from the database
        [self checkIfExists];
    }
    self.checkLaunch = 1;
}

- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
    self.currentUser.username = [self.username text];
    self.currentUser.phone = [self.phone text];
    _currentUser.age = [self.userAge text];
    _currentUser.school = [self.school text];
}

-(void) loadUser {
    // load the data out again
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Users where name='%@'", self.currentUser.name];
    if (self.queryResult == nil) {
        self.queryResult = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDatafromDB:query]];
    }

    // set the textfields with values if there are any
    if (self.queryResult.count > 0) {
        self.username = [[self.queryResult objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.columnNames indexOfObject:@"username"]];
        self.phone = [[self.queryResult objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.columnNames indexOfObject:@"phone"]];
        self.something = [[self.queryResult objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.columnNames indexOfObject:@"todo"]];
        self.school = [[self.queryResult objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.columnNames indexOfObject:@"school"]];
        self.userAge = [[self.queryResult objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.columnNames indexOfObject:@"age"]];
    }
}
```

I am guessing it is because when trying to query and assign the value to textfields and textviews, the value might be nil. Please if anyone can tell me what will be the possible mistake I made?

Answer (score 1):

`resignFirstResponder` is missing while dismissing the keyboard. Try this:

```
- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {
    [username resignFirstResponder];
    [userAge resignFirstResponder];
    [phone resignFirstResponder];
    [school resignFirstResponder];

    self.currentUser.username = [self.username text];
    self.currentUser.phone = [self.phone text];
    _currentUser.age = [self.userAge text];
    _currentUser.school = [self.school text];
}
```